# WCF more than 50 concurent long running request

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

Hy, I have a WCF Test service, it does nothing only a thread.sleep(10000) and I call it from 200 clients.
The problem is the response time is greater and greater, after 10 minutes over 40 sec... 
I have tired to change web.config and machine.config too.
We have Windows 2008 r2 and IIS 7.5

In my web.config

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="400" maxConcurrentInstances="2000" />
```

In my macine.config

```
<processModel autoConfig="false" logLevel="None" maxIoThreads="1000" maxWorkerThreads="1000" minIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="100" />
```

In my Aspnet.config

```
<applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="5000" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" requestQueueLimit="5000" />
```

The WCF Service:

```
public interface ISampleService
{

    [OperationContractAttribute]
    string SampleMethod(string msg);
}

public class SampleService : ISampleService
{


    public string SampleMethod(string msg)
    {
         Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://microsoft.wcf.documentation")]
public interface ISampleService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> SampleMethod(string msg);
}

public class SampleService : ISampleService
{
    async Task<string> ISampleService.SampleMethod(string msg)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew((param) =>
                                         {
                                             return "Return from Server : " + msg;
                                         }, TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning);
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

And i need only the web.config changes:

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="2000" />
```